Reading multiple push-button switches on a raspberry pi using an mcp23017 over C++
Having followed various tutorials on the web (i.e. 1,2), I have made the following connections:

To enhance clarity, I post another picture depicting the connections on the mpc23017 using a cropped frame from the official datasheet.

Even though officially deprecated (as stated by the author), I am using the wiringPi, (which is fairly maintained by the community) using the following piece of code:
#include <iostream>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <mcp23017.h>

int main (){

        wiringPiSetupGpio();
        mcp23017Setup(100, 0x20); //$ sudo i2cdetect -y 1 --> gives the address 20.

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
                pinMode(100 + i, INPUT);
        }

        while( true ){
                for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
                        int sig = digitalRead(100 + i);
                        std::cout<<sig<<" ";
                }std::cout<<std::endl;

                delay(500);
        }
        return 0;
}

... but I am getting irrelevant output.
...
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
...

As a software programmer rather than an electrical engineer, I would definitely appreciate some help here..
image links:
img1
img1
img2

Edit:
As well mentioned by @Stefan, the issue was the resistors. To make things work, one has to connect a resistor to every switch.
However as well mentioned by @Uwe, using the MCP23017, you don't have to, because MPC23017 supports them internally(refer to page 22 on the datasheet). Therefore, what worked at the end is to update the code as follows:
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
    pinMode(100 + i, INPUT);
    pullUpDnControl (100 + i, PUD_UP) ; // <-- activate the pull-up resistors
}

I kindly thank you both!

Edit 2:
Despite not affecting the issue described in the post, I realized I miss-drew the SDA & SCL connections on the diagrams, misinterpreting the primary wiring. The connections seen in the corrected image (image 1) depict the actual wiring (SDA->GPIO 2, SCL->GPIO 3), but I found it helpful to replace the image for anyone who visits the post afterward

This kind of switches is pressed by a user and read by the microprocessor. But they are not controlled by the processor. You may control a LED connected to an output, LED on, LED off, LED blink, modify the intensity of the LED by using pulse width modulation PWM. To read a switch by the processor, there must be a defined voltage for both states of the switch, open and closed. See page 4 of the MCP23017/MCP23S17 datasheet, definition of V_IL and V_IH.

Which MCP23017 library do you use?

@Jens As mentioned in the post, I am using the wiringPi.

Just connecting switches from the inputs of the MCP23017 to ground is not how it works.
An input is usually floating, which means the voltage is not defined, which means the input state is not defined and can change/toggle spontaneously.
Add a pull-up or pull-down resistor to each switch, like indicated in the links that you posted.

thank you @Stefan. I ll try that and come back to elaborate on the post

The MCP23017 has programmable internal pull-up resistors, see page 22 of the datasheet. If the internal pull-up resistors are activated, the switch may be connected from the input to GND and no external resistor is necessary.

@Stefan Wyss was right. The problem was the resistors. I have just tested it and it works like a charm.

As I check the datasheet, @Uwe is right too! MCP23017 has the resistors integrated internally, so the only thing to clarify now is how to activate them .

well at first thank you so much. In an example in the wiringPi, there is a line that activates the internal pull-up resistors. One uses pullUpDnControl() to activate them. And that was it. Thank you again!

@cestpasmoi Some more information here https://wolles-elektronikkiste.de/en/mcp23x1y-port-expander with an English and a German version, sorry no French version.

@Uwe Oh thank you very much, I ll check it out. I am greek by the way! It just happens to love the French language ;)
